# How to set a Job Due Date in Activiti 5.22.0?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-enterprise

I got a reference to a Job object like this:

```
Job timer = managementService.createJobQuery().processInstanceId(execution.getParentId()).singleResult();
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I set the timer due date to an arbitrary
date or time period in Activiti 5.22.0?

I could not find a suitable method in ManagementService or Job class.

Best regards.

Comment: its not possible to change timer at runtime, better use a proper ISO8601 timer intervals in process definition

Answer (score 1):

For me, I found only one way to do this:
Create a new timer and set config from the old one.
This is a piece example of how I did this, do not forget to fix it, to avoid NPE

```
TimerEntity oldTimer = (TimerEntity) managementService.createJobQuery()
                                            .processInstanceId("YOUR_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID")
                                            .timers()
                                            .singleResult();
    commandExecutor.execute(new Command<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void execute(CommandContext commandContext) {
            oldTimer.delete();
            TimerEntity newTimer = new TimerEntity();
            newTimer.setJobHandlerConfiguration(oldTimer.getJobHandlerConfiguration());
            newTimer.setJobHandlerType(oldTimer.getJobHandlerType());
            newTimer.setExclusive(oldTimer.isExclusive());
            newTimer.setRepeat(oldTimer.getRepeat());
            newTimer.setRetries(oldTimer.getRetries());
            newTimer.setEndDate(oldTimer.getEndDate());
            newTimer.setExecutionId(oldTimer.getExecutionId());
            newTimer.setProcessInstanceId(oldTimer.getProcessInstanceId());
            newTimer.setProcessDefinitionId(oldTimer.getProcessDefinitionId());
            newTimer.setTenantId(oldTimer.getTenantId());
            // Sets a new date
            newTimer.setDuedate(new Date());
            commandContext.getJobEntityManager().schedule(newTimer);
            return null;
        }

    });
```